# Spring @Repository @Document is not necessary?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-annotations

I have a spring boot application and connected to Mongo DB.
I know all most all of documents or blogs said the sample code should like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {

}

@Document
public class Product {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int price;
}
```

But I found even if I remove @Repository and @Document annotations. The application still can start without error. Spring still can know ProductRepository is spring bean and also can CRUD `Product` collection.

So does these not necessary to add  @Repository and @Document? Or is there any difference add or not add?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessery.

Spring can found it, because you extends the `MongoRepository` interface, and add `Product` as it type.

`@Repository` is useful anyway, for example if you create a custom repository.

`@Document` is also, if you want to specify custom property values, for example collection name..

Answer (score 2):

The annotation `@Repository` registers a class as a Spring bean which makes it autowirable. Spring Data doesn't use annotations but provides functionality through extending reposotory classes such as `JpaRepository` or `MongoRepository`.